# Flex 4.5 Image loading from assets folder takes too much time

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I'm using flex 4.5.1.  I have image in my flex application. I make a http request and retrieve the file path of picture that lies under the assets folder in the project workspace. I have a label on the screen too and i updated at the same time i update the image. Normally they should be updated at the same time but image is updated 1 or 2 seconds after the label is updated.

The following code is the image and its id with initial source file:

```
<s:BitmapImage id="personImage" visible="true" left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10"
                               fillMode="scale" scaleMode="stretch" source="assets/TT.jpg"
                               verticalAlign="bottom" verticalCenter="10"/>
```

I set the image as follows:

```
if(fileExist){
        personImage.source=lastEntranceService.lastResult.person.image;
        personImage.validateNow();
}else{
     personImage.source = "assets/TT.jpg";
      personImage.validateNow();
  }

lastEntranceService.lastResult.person.image; //is the filepath of the image file
```

I use validate function too but i remember that somewhere in the forum I read that flex image is loaded asynchronously. 
Are there any ways for me to show the image at the screen as soon as label is updated. I have a time constraint so I can not wait for image to be updated and then update label.
Images vary in dimensions and which means that the images in the asset folder is different. When shown on screen the image (which needs to be shown) is resized to some constant size.

Thank you for your attention and your time.

Comment: What about embedding your image in your compiled application?

Answer (score 0):

You must loaded first, than set bitmap source and label text.

```
private var timStart :uint;

private function click()  {
    bitmapLoader = new Loader();
    bitmapLoader.load(new URLRequest(lastEntranceService.lastResult.person.image));
    bitmapLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);  

    timStart = getTimer();
}
```

...

```
private function loaded(e :Event) {

    var timeNeedToLoad:uint = getTimer() - timStart;

    personImage.source = bitmapLoader;
    label.text = 'Bitmap: '+ lastEntranceService.lastResult.person.image;
}
```

**Edit:**

Check time need to load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will not decrease the loading time of image. It just waits image to be loaded to update label. What i primarily need is to load image immediately as i update label. This can be considered a solution for the same problem without time constraint right?

Comment: Is time different when you load other formats like png or when bitmap size is smaller?

Comment: I use only jpeg files, that i think it might have better performance. There is another thing which i forgot to mention the image sizes can differ in asset folder and they are all resized to some constant size.

Comment: And what happend if you don't scale bitmap?

Comment: It automatically does, how can i force it not to scale the image

Comment: Try `fillMode="clip"` and also see what happend if you change other properties like `scaleMode, smooth, smoothingQuality`... Count the time it takes to load bitmap when you use Loader - I edit my answer.